# Is there a way to replace all substrings in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean all instances of `[xReturn]` from my dataframe and replace it with a blank space ( ). However when I try the code below it only removes the values that are `[xReturn]` and nothing else. For example `"abcde[xReturn]fghij"` remains the same while `"[xReturn]"` becomes  . I have tried setting `regex=True` but that does not work either. It removes any instance of any of the characters in `[xReturn]`. I want `"abcde[xReturn]fghij"` to become `"abcdefghij"`. Is there any way to do this using `df.replace()`?

My code:

```
df = df.replace('[xReturn]', ' ')
```

Comment: Give the code to generate the dataframe and a also provide sample dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.astype(str).replace("\[xReturn\]", "", regex=True)
```

Comment: Yes forgot that [ and ] are regex special characters. This worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace('[xReturn]', ' ', regex=False)
```

`str` allows you to use vectorized string function as you want to perform `replace()` operation on the string content, not on the dataFrame itself.

**EDIT**
If you want to perform the operation on all `str` columns you can do as follows:

```
for c in df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace('[xReturn]', ' ', regex=False)
```

Comment: "There is no builtin method" is incorrect. See my solution.